# android achartengine : fill line chart with pattern

Tags: android, achartengine

Am trying out a series line chart with achartengine in an android app. Here's a screenshot of it :

[image]

Each colored box/rectangle is one series. I have now filled all the series with grey color. But I want to fill then with some patterns, like say, criss-cross lines. How can I do this? Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

```
FillOutsideLine fill = new FillOutsideLine(FillOutsideLine.Type.BOUNDS_ALL);

fill.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.pink));
renderer.addFillOutsideLine(fill);`
```